# Is there any IC which can generate -12V using a +12V input?

Tags: battery-charging

generating -12V using +12V.

Is a simple inverter circuit is enough to generate a -12v using +12V voltage supply?

Comment: `Is there any IC which can generate -12V using a +12V input?` Yes, there is. Google is your friend.

Comment: More information would be helpful.  What is the source of your +12V?  What do you need to power with -12V?

Comment: I use a solar panel to power two batteries. The circuit is as described below.

Comment: I use a solar panel to power two batteries. The circuit is as described below.  I'm using one 12V battery to generate -12V in the other battery. which I'm using to power the op amps and other circuits. The problem is that I have only one solar panel which can power one 12V battery , so I ave to generate -12V using the same power supply.

Comment: Depending on other constraints [ICL7660A](http://www.intersil.com/en/products/power-management/isolated-power/charge-pumps/ICL7660.html) may be a possibility.

Comment: Thank you ..That was helpful. Now that I've specified the requirements? Does  ICL7660A suite the requirements? or is there any other possibility.?

Comment: You haven't specified the output current needed from the -12V power rail. Depending on the complexity of your op-amp circuits it might be easier to get them to work from a single ended 12 volts.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use an inverting buck-boost regulator. The [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576hv.pdf) is one of the simplest parts to use, if it fits your requirements. Assuming your current requirement at -12 is not too high, you can consider this:

[image]

Be sure to read the datasheet (linked above) to understand the limitations etc.

Comment: the output current will be in the order of mA.

Comment: You might want to consider using +/-5V for the instrumentation supplies rather than +/-12, then you can use a charge pump IC without worries.